# Call a AngularJS function with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an angular app which need to load a php page in view. Everything works great. But I need to run an angular function after the php code loads.

How can I call an angular function from php. This is the function I need to call.

```
$emit('iso-method', {name:null, params:null})
```

I could write call a javascript function but I'm unsure how to call an angular function with that either.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'myfunction();'
   , '</script>'
;
```

Comment: How do you load view?

Comment: with the included router ` <div ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>`

Comment: Then just put emit code into corresponding controller.

Comment: Thats the thing. There isn't a controller because the view is loading a php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call an angular function from PHP. But you could call an angular function from javascript or jquery. I was stuck with same problem in one of my project, what I did See below examples.

Call angular function from javascript:
Your controller element like

```
<div id="demoElement" ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController">
</div>
```

and in your script

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        angular.element(document.getElementById('demoElement')).scope().emit('name','params');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great Idea! The code as written errors in Angular. I did have a little luck with `angular.element(isotopeContainer).scope();` but couldn't get any further than that.

Comment: Please share your complete code. So we can help you more on it.